# Model in MVC is it business logic or data displayed by the View

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

As many others I'm having problems with understanding MVC pattern. To be more precise let's talk about Grail web apps. My undertanding is that Model is Services and Domain Classes. And typical usage of controller would be (actually for this particular usage we may call Person.get(id) directly from the controller, but suppose we make a call through the service):

```
def getPerson(String id){
    Person person = peopleService.get(id);
    render(view: "person", model: person)
}
```

In this case it turned out that the service method has returned domain object, which in case is a part of Model. But it might be the case that service method does not modify domain object or do modify it, but returns, say, boolean value.

```
def savePerson(Person p){
    boolean saved = peopleService.save(p);
    render(view: "actionresult", model: saved)
}
```

In this case boolean value is not a part of Model, however it's named as model in render method.

So I have three hypothesis:

- There are two models: application layer model that is responsible for business logic AND data that is used to render view
- MVC is completely presentational layer pattern and have nothing to do with business-logic layer, in this case model is just the data displayed by the view
- Model is service layer and domain classes, controller triggers model update through service method call and the data used for rendering view should somehow represent model state that's why it's also called model in render function

What do you think about it?

Comment: for me the "model" is just all variables sent to the "view" directed by "controller" and services are just for not repeat your code again and aigain in controllers

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are right in your hypothesis - MVC can mean different things in different contexts. When you make a MVC framework or an application based on the MVC pattern, you also define what the "model" is supposed to be in that context. It can be a complex domain model or simply a data access layer, for example.

I think that it's safe to say that in the context of a complex web application built using a common MVC framework, the "model" is not necessarily identical to the model of the business logic. The underlying business model of a "product" in a webshop can have information about suppliers and purchase prices for example, which you might never want to expose in the webshop interface.

So in that case you might want to use a different "model" that exposes some, but not all, of it's properties to the MVC framework.

There is a concept called [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) that considers this explicitly. Simply put the "view model" is a mapping of the "proper" model for the purposes of displaying in a particular view.

Answer (score 1):

Grails is very clear on separating different layers.

**To be very simple, in Grails world:**

`M`: Models are your `Domain` classes modeling your data layer (tables, collections, etc)

`V`: Views are your `gsp` pages or your presentation layer

`C`: Controllers are routers, distributing responsibility to other classes however, they could be easily misused for other duties.

`Services` are just helper classes responsible for your business logic with special characteristics (transaction, etc).